# Is it sufficient to do website login throttling based on the username?

Tags: security, authentication, throttling

For example, if user `fred123` has failed login `X` times in the last `Y` minutes, then I would block `fred123` from being able to attempt login for some period of time. But during that period of time other users wouldn't be blocked from logging in. Is that good enough?

Is seems like it would work because a brute forcer would only be able to try each username `X` times. I would be setting `X` and `Y` to low numbers - probably both less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

You're making an assumption that a brute force login would always target the same username and try different passwords. If that were true, then it would be fine.

However, assuming the attacker had a list of usernames from your server, they could try an obvious password, such as 'password' and step through each user to see if anyone was using it. That would completely bypass your theory of how an attack may occur.

A better system would be to log the IP address of the incoming user and count the number of failed attempts that took place from that IP, in a known period of time. If it exceeds an amount, then block attempts from that IP for a length of time. Doing this is less disruptive to your users, if it's someone else trying to login with their username.

Linux has a similar system called [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which takes this approach for people trying to login to servers.

What you should also do is try to think about what your website does and how would you compromise the security.

Answer (score 0):

It is a start, but if you are paranoid about failed login attempts, then i would also throttle on ip address.

And if you are really really paranoid i would throttle on global failed attempt, and increase the lockout duration for each attempt, inside lets say a 10 min window